# How to simultaneously hide and show content and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, show-hide

I have a problem and I need your help. I have several links (in `<aside>`) leading to several different menus (in `<section>`). On click over the link, only the relevant div in `<section>` is shown, the rest are hidden. This part is ok and working. What is not working is when I click over an image:

1. the current div (`.menu`) in `<section>` should be hidden;
2. the same picture (with bigger size) should be shown;
3. when you click once again over the big image, the big image should disappear and the current div in `.menu` (the one that was hidden on the first step) should appear one more time. Sort of toggling between content.

So if I click on a picture on the "second div" content, the same picture with bigger size should be show (the "second div" content should be hidden) and when I click once again over the big picture it should disappear and the "second div" content to be returned.

I tried with `toggle()` but had no success. Either I did not use it correctly, or it is not suitable for my case. This is where I managed to reach to.

I will really appreaciate your support - how to show only the hidden div, not all hidden div's. Right now, when you click on the big image it did not show the hidden div.

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  $("div.menu:first-child").show();
});

$(".nav a").on("click", function() {
  $("div.menu").fadeOut(30);

  var targetDiv = $(this).attr("data-rel");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#" + targetDiv).fadeIn(30);
  }, 30);
});

var pictures = $(".img-1, .img-2").on("click", function() {
  $("div.menu:active").addClass("hidden");

  //how to reach out only the current, active div (not all div's in .menu)?

  $(".menu").hide();
  var par = $("section")
    .prepend("<div></div>")
    .append("<img id='pic' src='" + this.src + "'>");

  var removePictures = $("#pic").on("click", function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(".hidden").show();
  });

});
```

```css
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
.menu:first-child {
  display: block;
}
.row {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.img-1,
.img-2 {
  width: 120px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <aside>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#content1" data-rel="content1">To first div</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#content2" data-rel="content2">To second div</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#content3" data-rel="content3">To third div</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <section>
    <div class="menu" id="content1">
      <h3>First Div</h3>
      <div class="present">

        <div class="row">
          <div>
            <p>Blah-blah-blah. This is the first div.</p>
            <img class="img-1" src="http://www.newyorker.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Stokes-Hello-Kitty2-1200.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div>
            <img class="img-2" src="https://jspwiki-wiki.apache.org/attach/Slimbox/doggy.bmp">
            <p>Blah-blah-blah. This is the first div.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu" id="content2">
      <h3>Second Div</h3>
      <div class="present">

        <div class="row">
          <div>
            <p>
              Blah-blah-blah. This is the second div.
            </p>
            <img class="img-1" src="http://www.newyorker.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Stokes-Hello-Kitty2-1200.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div>
            <img class="img-2" src="https://jspwiki-wiki.apache.org/attach/Slimbox/doggy.bmp">
            <p>
              Blah-blah-blah. Yjis is the second div.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu" id="content3">
      <h3>Third Div</h3>
      <div class="present">

        <div class="row">
          <div>
            <p>
              Blah-blah-blah. This is the third div.
            </p>
            <img class="img-1" src="http://www.newyorker.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Stokes-Hello-Kitty2-1200.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div>
            <img class="img-2" src="https://jspwiki-wiki.apache.org/attach/Slimbox/doggy.bmp">
            <p>
              Blah-blah-blah. This is the third div.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Sorry for the ugly sketch and pictures - it is only to get an idea what it should look like....

Comment: within jQuery event handler ...`this` is element acted on. Want to do something with parent ...`$(this).parent().doSomething()`  or `$(this).parent().find('.someClass').doSomething()`. Read through API for all the ways to traverse...each method shows examples

Comment: I have read many documentations and tried many, many things. If I had managed to did what I wanted I was not going to ask how to did it and what I have missed. I need written decision, not an advice "go there and read it". I have already read it and that did not help me...

Comment: well sorry for trying to help. You need to start from `$(this)`

Comment: Sorry if I sounded rude. I'm just really pissed off of this non-working function and really do not know how to solve it.

Comment: The main, main question is: how to take only the active div, hide it and then make it once again active (the rest should keep being hidden)?
What do you mean by start from $(this)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it's poor form to ask on Stack Overflow how to code for a specific behavior. However, that takes some understanding of the libraries you're using, and what you are trying to achieve. Hopefully, my answer will help you better articulate and form your questions in the future.

Here's a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/hwd4b0ag/

In particular, I've modified your last click listener:

```
var pictures = $(".img-1, .img-2").on("click", function() {
  var parentDiv = $(this).closest('div.menu').hide();

  var blownUpPic = $("<img>").attr({
  id: 'pic',
  src: this.src,
  'data-parent': parentDiv.attr('id')
  })
  .appendTo("section")
  .on('click', function() {
    $('#' + $(this).attr('data-parent')).show();
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

Now, let's review it!

First,

```
var parentDiv = $(this).closest('div.menu').hide();
```

In a jQuery listener, the `this` variable stores the current javascript DOM element that is the recipient of the event listener. In your case, it refers to an element that matches `".img-1, .img-2"`.

`.closest(selector)` will traverse up the DOM (including the current element) and find the first matching element for the provided selector. In this case, it finds your container div with class `menu`. Then we hide that div and save a reference to it in a variable.

Next, we create a full-sized version of the picture and assign it some attributes:

```
var blownUpPic = $("<img>").attr({
  id: 'pic',
  src: this.src,
  'data-parent': parentDiv.attr('id')
  })
```

We set the `data-parent` attribute to the `id` of our container div, so we have a *reference back to it later*.

We then add our image to the DOM:

```
.appendTo("section")
```

And declare a new click listener for it:

```
.on('click', function() {
    $('#' + $(this).attr('data-parent')).show();
    $(this).remove();
  });
```

With `$(this).attr('data-parent')` we use the reference to our container div that we assigned earlier, and then retrieve that element by its `id`. We unhide the container div and remove the full-sized image.

All done!

---

There are better ways to code this, but I think this is a good next step for you that's analogous to your current code.

Comment: Kevin, I really appreciate your answer. As you may see I am novice and still do not have enough knowledge how to do things work properly. You are right, I do not have good understanding but one day, I strongly hope, I will. Sorry for asking in an inappropriate way (that was my first question in here) so still need some more experience. Nevertheless, it was very helpful for me to see a written (working) code with explanations what is doing what. Now I have a good base to step over and review. Thank you one more time for Your time spent to write and explain :)